# Custom scheme doesn't seem to launch in the app intent

Tags: android, oauth

I'm trying to create an Android app that needs to use OAuth to authenticate (with the Google Wave data API)

I've specified a custom scheme in my `AndroidManifest.xml` so that any views to a url beginning "braindump://" should go to my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.enigmagen.braindump"
    android:versionName="0.1"
    android:versionCode="1">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"></uses-sdk>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".BrainDump"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="braindump" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

All that happens though is that after the redirect, the browser address shows the correct URL, but the page content is

You do not have permission to open this page.
   braindump://rest_of_address_here

Is there a specific permission that needs to be set to allow this sort of behaviour?

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same problem (OAuth) and this is how I fixed it.

I've separated my Main from the class that will act on the URI.

Here's how the AndroidManifest.xml should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

[snip]

          <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="MainActivity">
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
          </activity>
          <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="OAUTHActivity">
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="oauth" />
           </intent-filter>
          </activity>
         </application>

    [/snip]
```

And I was able to open URIs like `myscheme//oauth?oauth_verifier=xxx&oauth_token=yyy`

Comment: Adrian did you mean `myscheme//oauth?oauth_verifier=xxx&oauth_token=yyy` or `myscheme://oauth?oauth_verifier=xxx&oauth_token=yyy`

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it's possible to do it with only one activity, just creating one more intent filter. Like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action   android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>     
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="my_scheme" android:host="my_app_host.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is exactly the cause of your problem, but I got this same error "You do not have permission to open this page" and it was because I was using a scheme with a capital letter. eg "Celly" instead of "celly". This worked fine in the emulator but failed on real devices. Changing it all to lowercase fixed it.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I feel your pain. Gotta use all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [common tasks](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html) that should be:

```
<scheme android:name="braindump" />
```

Comment: Seems to depend on where you look http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html