# Intent filter to catch links from SMS doesn't work

Tags: android, hyperlink, sms, intentfilter

I've read many posts on stackoverflow and doc on the Android API in order to be able to catch links from SMS or mail. For example, if I receive a SMS containing a link like myapp://hello, I want to to be clickable and to open my application once clicked.

I found how to do it using an intent filter on the activity I want to activate. Here is my code:

```
   <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
<data android:scheme="myapp"></data>
```

I tried it first with android:scheme="http" and it worked well (when I clicked a link from a SMS, Android asked the user which app to use: browser or myapp).
However when I want to do so with myapp instead of http, it doesn't work...indeed the link myapp://hello is not clickable...so it's impossible to launch myapp clicking on it...

Do you have any idea ? Do I have to activate something, somewhere to tell Android to parse this kind of addresses ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [android custom url scheme..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023273/android-custom-url-scheme), also possibly of [Custom scheme doesn't seem to launch in the app intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129024/custom-scheme-doesnt-seem-to-launch-in-the-app-intent)

Comment: @Vincent : you found the solution of your problem? I am facing the same problem but no luck. Please help.